# ApostropheCMS: How do I populate the _children key under apostrophe-pages when there are in fact children?

Tags: javascript, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

This question is the same as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401302/why-is-the-apostrophe-pages-children-array-is-always-empty), but the only answer is something I had already tried by following the [docs](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/advanced-topics/advanced-pages-topics/children-and-joins#projections-and-children) to no avail. I need to access 4 levels deep of pages. I currently have the following included in my lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js:

```js
  addFields: [
    {
      name: '_pages',
      type: 'joinByArray',
      withType: 'apostrophe-page',
      label: 'Pages',
      idsField: 'pageIds',
      filters: {
        children: {
          depth: 4,
          areas: false
        },
        projection: {
          title: 4,
          slug: 4,
          rank: 4,
          level: 4,
          path: 4
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I even tried passing '1' as it says to do in the docs and still only returns an empty array under the "_children" key when logging out data.

and I have the following in my app.js file:

```js
'apostrophe-pages': {
      filters: {
        ancestors: {
          children: {
            depth: 4
          }
        },
        children: {
          depth: 4
        }
      },
```

No matter what it's still empty. How can I get the _children key to populate accurately as my navigation tree shows?

Comment: When you say you get "nothing," what does that mean? How are you trying to access the data and what exactly are you getting back?

Comment: I have a front end app that I'm feeding data to from the CMS. I'm logging out the data and no matter what, it still returns an empty array under the key of "_children"

Comment: I have set up a test case for this and also get the `_children: []` property .. If you could, would you open a GitHub issue @mk23 ? https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/

Comment: I opened the issue here: https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/2092